# Change label days according to week selected in input of type week

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the dates of my labels using Chart.js, but that it shows me the days of the selected week in an input type week, the code I have is the following:

```
<div class="card-body">
        <input class="form-control" type="week" value="2021-W32" id="example-week-input">
        <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
      </div>
```

here below I leave the javascript code that is executed.

```
var ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx1, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['09/08/2021', '10/08/2021', '11/08/2021', '12/08/2021', '13/08/2021', '14/08/2021', '15/08/2021'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Ventas Dirias Sitio Web',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(228, 0, 43)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(228, 0, 43)', 
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }       
        ]},
    options: {}
});
```

I would appreciate the help too much.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the rendering of the week using something like this:

```
// function to get first day of the week
function FirstDayOfWeek(w, y) {
  let date = new Date(y, 0, (1 + (w) * 7)); 
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + (1 - date.getDay())); // 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday etc
  return date
}

// function to format the date to dd/MM/yyyy
function FormatDate(d)
{
  var dd = d.getDate();
  var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;

  var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
      dd = '0' + dd;
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
      mm = '0' + mm;
  }
  return dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
}

function RenderChart() {
  let week = document.getElementById("example-week-input").value
  let year = week.split("-")[0]*1,
    weekNumber = week.split("-")[1].substring(1)*1; // to skip the W

  let currentDay = FirstDayOfWeek(weekNumber, year); // get the first day of the week
  
  let chartLabels = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  {
    chartLabels.push(FormatDate(currentDay));
    currentDay.setDate(currentDay.getDate() + 1); // move to next day
  }

  // render chart with the new days label
  var ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx1, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: chartLabels,
          datasets: [{
              label: 'Ventas Dirias Sitio Web',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(228, 0, 43)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(228, 0, 43)', 
              data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
          }       
          ]},
      options: {}
  });
}
```

Then you would just need to modify your week picker, adding the call to "RenderChart()" in the "onchange" event. You can also call that function when the page loads to automatically render the selected week.

```
<input class="form-control" type="week" value="2021-W32" id="example-week-input" onchange="RenderChart()">
```